# Embedded Login Page in website

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, embed

I'm working on a website that utilizes information from an external website and presents it in a neat chart.

The issue is that the user will have to login to that website in order to see the information (i.e. like logging into facebook).

I'm trying to develop something like embedding the login page of that external website into my website and then have the user login that way (see below)

```
<object data=http://www.website.com  width="600" height="400"> <embed id="test" src=http://www.website.com  width="600" height="400"> </embed> Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. </object>
```

My question is how are you able to know if the user has logged in? In the embedded window, I can log in and see the page but my website doesn't know that I have logged in. Is there a way to actively check the URL of the embedded page to see if has changed (i.e. you have logged in)?

I've tried just refreshing the page but the source link for the embed object is the same.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know if any cookies are set when the user logs in? http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

For security/technical reasons, you can't directly retrieve whether or not the user is logged in to some other page unless there's an API, which most social media sites have. If you own the page, you can also build one.

Otherwise, if you have enough traffic available, you can also request the login data via a form that gets submitted to your server and then do some stuff to have the server login to that other website and retrieve the information you wanted. However, that's not feasible in a high-load environment (many users), because of multiple reasons:

- The server would have to logout and login very often, which will take up a lot of performance
- That would also cause a lot of traffic, as I don't see how you'd retrieve the info once logged in other than requesting some web page and parsing it
- Finally, because of all those requests from the same IP in a short window of time, the server of whatever website you're looking at will end up denying you access because you've been spamming it with requests.
- Of course, you could use an iframe that hides once the user has logged in (you can detect when it reloads and the hide it via `display:none`), then parsing its contents, but I doubt that'll work as the access to iframe contents is restricted for security reasons.